# Equality of norms on $L^1 (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus

Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and define

$\phi(y) = \int_{y}^{y+1} f(x) dx$

Show that $\phi$ is $L^1 (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and $|| \phi||_1 = ||f||_1$

Comment: Equality of the norms does generally not hold.

Comment: Of course, equality of the norms should holds for $f \ge 0$. But I have problem to start the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**  Just start writing:
$$ \|\phi\|_1
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\phi(y)| \,dy
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|\int_y^{y+1} f(x) \,dx\right| \,dy
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_y^{y+1} f(x) \,dx \,dy
$$
using that $f\ge 0$ at the end there.  There is a manoeuvre which should leap to mind now, as it should leap to mind every time you see nested integrals...

Comment: I would like to apply the Fubini theorem: 
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{y+1} f(x) dx dy = \int_{y+1}^{y} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dy dx = \int_{y}^{y+1} ||f||_1 dy = ||f||_1$. Is this correct? I have to prove that i can use Fubini theorem.

Comment: Almost correct.  You need to change the bounds when you exchange the integrals, though.  The initial double integral is over $(x,y)$ such that $-\infty < y < \infty$ and $y\le x\le y+1$; rearrange that to express the range of $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{y+1} f(x) dx dy = \int_{x}^{x-1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx dy = \int_{x}^{x-1} ||f||_1 dy = ||f||_1$ Now it should be correct. Is that also a proof that $\phi \in L^1( \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$? Why could I use Fubini theorem?

Comment: There are a couple versions of Fubini.  What conditions are there in the version you have?

Comment: I want to know that $\phi \in L^1 (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, to use Fubini, because then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{y+1} f(x) dx dy$ exists

Comment: Ok, to use the version of Fubini where the function has to be integrable, write the proof backwards: start from $\|f\|_1 = \int_{x-1}^x \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx\,dy$, which you know is finite.  (It's probably easier to use the version of Fubini which only requires the function to be nonnegative; this is sometimes called Tonelli's theorem.)

Comment: Oops, of course I meant $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{x-1}^x f(x)\,dy \,dx$.